# VSCode interpreting OpenEdge line as HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code, openedge, progress-4gl, webspeed

Some of the code I'm working with has some OpenEdge embaded in the html files with the <?ws> tag. To not confuse the formatter, I added the following line in the *settings.json*:

`"html.format.contentUnformatted": "?ws"`

Everything is fine except when I get lines like this:

```
 {&out} '<script TYPE="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript" >' skip.
```

VSCode will ignore the first "{&out} ' " and then interpret the rest has HTML. Therefor it thinks it is in a script tag. I'm still able to run the code. But it's cloging the "broblem" tab with hundreds of errors. Is there a way to fix this?